# term document matrix seems combine words? "sootawn" "abilitiesbrush"

Tags: r

```
head(myTDM)
                Docs
Terms              1  2
  abatement       20  0
  abilities       18 80
  abilitiesbrush   0  1
  abilitiescreate  0 13
  abilitiesmarket  0  6
  able             0 30
```

I was thinking, I was doing something wrong since the outcome is the combination of 2 or sometimes more words then I saw the same thing in a text mining book so I really wonder why it just appears like that? many thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide some context? What is `myTDM`? What specifically is your issue?

Comment: Without data and code it is difficult to see what is going on. But probably a combination of removing numbers and whitespace. Try to create a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please add packages used and sample data. Use `dput` for sample data.

Comment: thank u very much guys, I just found out:) collapse=" " rather then collapse=""  then I saw again "acceptancereject" then I go back to document and  it was accullay acceptance-reject in the document. so the reason why it seems all together  beacuse I removed the puctuation for clean.corpus :)